# present perfect and past simple

Tags: tense

**I moved to this city last year.
I have been in this since one year ago.**

*I have been here since last year.*

Would you tell me if the bold parts mean the same? and the italic part is correct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PO's first sentence in bold " I moved to this city last year" is grammatically correct.

On the hand, the second sentence is not correct.  We don't use "ago" in the present perfect. However, we can say "I moved to this city one year ago.

The last  sentence "I have been here since last year" is correct.